# React Native GraphQL use Apollo : Pass array to mutation input

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I just use apollo to call api graph QL for some days

I just have a simple question

how can I pass an array like a variable to mutation

in my code, line 7, i want to pass "waypoints" array to mutation.

Please!!!

```
const GET_QUOTATION = gql`
    query($date: String!) {
      getQuotation(
        input: {
          pickupTime: $date
          serviceType: CAR
          waypoints: [
            {
              type: PICKUP
              address1: "Anson Road, #23-01"
              address2: "079906"
              location: {lat: "1.307274", lng: "103.883998"}
              name: "Jack"
              phone: "82187877"
            }
          ]
        }
      ) {
        delivery {
          provider
          price
        }
        poolWindow {
          price
          window
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const [getQuotation, quotationData] = useLazyQuery(GET_QUOTATION, {
    onCompleted() {
      console.log('-> success');
    },
    onError() {
      console.log('-> error');
    },
    variables: {
      date: '2021-03-12T18:54:00Z',
    },
  });
```

Comment: prepare and pass entire `input` object

Comment: @xadm can you talk more detail

Comment: ... use search?